# Getting the following error when trying to run the spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
> re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2021-06-18 12:42:19.152
> ERROR 21120 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
> : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'viewResolver' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]:
> Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'thymeleafViewResolver' defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafWebMvcConfiguration$ThymeleafViewResolverConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'thymeleafViewResolver' parameter 1; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'templateEngine' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine]: Factory
> method 'templateEngine' threw exception; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'securityDialect' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafSecurityDialectConfiguration.class]:
> Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
> [org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect]
> from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6]  at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
> [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
> [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
> [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
> [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
> [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
> [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
> com.example.demo.RegistrationandloginApplication.main(RegistrationandloginApplication.java:10)
> [classes/:na]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:1.8.0_232]   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:1.8.0_232]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> ~[na:1.8.0_232]   at
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> [spring-boot-devtools-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]

Comment: Can you share your application.properties file ?

Comment: @ThivankaW   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE